# adding a client side component in NavBar.jsx throws JSON parse error in Next JS 13.2

Tags: javascript, next.js13

I was building a small project based on Dave tutorials in Next js 13 . As soon as I add <Search /> in NavBar.jsx it given the following error -

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

It works fine as long as NavBar.jsx doesnt contain Search element . They both are in components directory

Code in Search.jsx

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Search() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSearch("");
        router.push(`/${search}/`);
    };

    return (
        <form
            className="w-50 flex justify-center md:justify-between"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
            <input
                type="text"
                value={search}
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                className="bg-white p-2 w-80 text-xl rounded-xl"
                placeholder="Search"
            />
            <button className="p-2 text-xl rounded-xl bg-slate-300 ml-2 font-bold">
                
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Code in NavBar.jsx

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import Search from "./Search";

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
        <nav className="bg-slate-600 p-4 flex justify-between flex-col md:flex-row sticky top-0 drop-shadow-xl">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-white grid place-content-center mb-2 md:mb-0">
                <Link href="/">WikiRocket!</Link>
            </h1>
            <Search />
        </nav>
    );
}
```

Tried to add a search bar in NavBar but it throws an error instead

Answer (score 0):

Change your export method from:

```
export default function Search(){
```

to:

```
const Search = () => {
{--rest of code--}

export default Search
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).